# Infinite, finite and arbitrarily large models.

Tags: logic, model-theory

How is it possible to have a sentence of First Order Logic with identity such that it has both finite and infinite models, but not arbitrarily large models?

Edited:
(arbitrarily large -finite- models)

Comment: Pretty sure the consistency theorem says that's not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be any sentence that is only satisfied by infinite models and let $\psi$ be the sentence $\forall x\forall y (x=y)$.  Then every model of $\varphi\vee\psi$ is either infinite or has at most one element.

Comment: I think Eric is right! The disjunction would have a finite model, with just one element, or an infinite one.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is false by upward Lowenheim-Skolem. It states that in FOL if a $\tau$-theory $T$ has an infinite model, then it has a model of any cardinality $\kappa \geq \max\{|\tau|,\aleph_0\}$.